# Conditional functions.php on page template

Tags: functions

I am creating a new page template (which essentially i am taking bits and pieces from a new theme). I have called this `template-flat.php`

Now in `functions.php` I am looking for a conditional statement to load some new js and css only for `template-flat.php` instead of the ones loaded by the old theme.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make use of the conditional tag [`is_page_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template)

> This Conditional Tag allows you to determine if you are in any page template. Optionally checks if a specific Page Template is being used in a Page. This is a boolean function, meaning it returns either TRUE or FALSE.

You can try something like

```
if( is_page_template( 'template-flat.php' ) ) {

    //Do something if the current template is template-flat.php

}else{

    //Do something else if the current template is not template-flat.php

}
```

Comment: thanks Pieter. Will this code also work if I am using the page template for custom post types?

Comment: This conditional tag will work regardless of post type. Whether or not your template will work with custom post type is up to the code inside the template :-)